# Where to put a sty file or as cls file of your own in a miktex structure?

Tags: packages

suppose I make personal files mybook.cls and mybook.sty, according to teximpatient or any texbook. I use UsbTex_1.5 related to miktex 2.9 and texwork. Where, in what directory do I put these files ?

Thanks for help
Alain

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2063/156344.

Comment: and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/156344.